# Why swap bytes in variable length encoding in the Thrift CompactProtocol?

Tags: encoding, integer, thrift, variable-length

I wondered why you had to swap bytes in the Trift CompactProtocol when encoding Ints with variable length.

Example taken from [Data Intensive Applications](https://books.google.de/books?id=zFheDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=variable%20length%20encoding%20thrift%20compactprotocol&source=bl&ots=BFlkq6r4sB&sig=ACfU3U1jDmnBnZDSO6B0cUPszBLFbFpuFw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPm8Dp2JrgAhXKMewKHU6pCbMQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=variable%20length%20encoding%20thrift%20compactprotocol&f=false) (online, page 120):

```
Number in Base 10 to be encoded: 1337
1337 in Base 2: 0010100 111001
Encoding first byte:  1|111011|0
Encoding second byte: 0|0010100
```

As you see the bytes have been swaped. Why is that?

Additional information: The first bit in the first byte represents that there is still one more byte to come. The last bit in the first byte represents the sign (positive in this case). The first bit in the last sign represents that there are no more additional bytes belonging to this number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an efficient way to encode small integers, or more precisely with small **absolute** values. The idea is explained in the [protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) very well:

> ZigZag encoding maps signed integers to unsigned integers so that
>   numbers with a small absolute value (for instance, -1) have a small
>   varint encoded value too. It does this in a way that "zig-zags" back
>   and forth through the positive and negative integers, so that -1 is
>   encoded as 1, 1 is encoded as 2, -2 is encoded as 3, and so on, as you
>   can see in the following table [...]

Small absolute values is a very common case.Large values are rather seldom. Hence for most use cases we would carry around a lot of (unnecessary) zeros with no added value. Unfortunately, for negative values it's a bit more complicated, because we have to care about the sign bit.

The ZigZag algorithm takes care of that in a very elegant and very efficient way.

Comment: but they are different, 1337 in each:

- thrift way: 0xf214 (in book)
- ZigZag encoding: 0x0a72 ((1337 << 1) ^ (1337 >> 63))